# How to push Client Machine values to web Server(database)

Tags: javascript, php

I am having client billing machine(Shopping and electricity billing machine),I need to push billing machine values to Database and store in database and display in web page.
How can I implement this using php and javascript.

Comment: Could you please add a little more description about the problem you have?

Comment: for example we have electricity billing machine , we will enter filed by using some hot keys , after billing we will generate report right, we are doing all this in one machine , we need to store that billing information to server which is any database , how can we do this...can you tell me any idea...